# How to attach VBA code in a xlsx build by PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, vba

after a lot of search, I did'nt found any answer to my question :(

I'm using PHPExcel to build some xlsx file.

I'm looking for a kind to attach a VBA code to my file.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know if what you want is currently doable with `PHPExcel`, but this link is worth a look [Excel 2007 - Macros - CustomUI](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/19017)

Answer (score 0):

It's not available within phpexcel, but there are a few workarounds discussed here:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/19017

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to answer but I had the same kind of problem and a workaround is, instead of writing in a new file, to read a file containing your VBA code and write in it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are suggesting; could you reword it?

Comment: I write an excel file that has always the same structure but the data may change according to the web user and I need some VBA instructions to customize the pies colors. So I've saved a final excel file in which I have manually inserted the VBA code and now I read this template and write data in it, and the VBA code is still there, using xlsm extension. It works fine!

Comment: I am trying to do so but my VBA code gets deleted, I use PHPExcel v.1.8.0----------- UPDATE-------- the template file needs to be .xlsm  and the output file too, that way works