# Can I create multiselect dropdown using PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Is it possible to create a multiselect dropdown ?

Excel allow to create dropdown choices with VBA, but I didn't find an option generating an excel and added multiselect dropdown with PhpSpreadsheet.

I found samples only single dropdown.

```
$validation = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B5')->getDataValidation();
$validation->setType( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$validation->setErrorStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$validation->setAllowBlank(false);
$validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$validation->setShowDropDown(true);
$validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$validation->setFormula1('"Item A,Item B,Item C"');
```

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any solution with phpspread.

Currently, I'm exporting with semicolon and manually adjusting in excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114753/how-to-attach-vba-code-in-a-xlsx-build-by-phpexcel/31370026 phpexcel didn't have ability to use vba code, don't know about phpspreadsheet

Comment: Correct, for this reason, the user exports the file and sets it directly in excel. I didn't find another solution.